# Chern character of Schubert structure sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $X_\lambda \subset Gr = Gr(k,n)$ be a Schubert variety in the Grassmannian and $\mathrm{ch} : K_0(Gr) \otimes \mathbb{Q} \to A^\bullet(Gr) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ the Chern character isomorphism.

Is there a simple description of $\mathrm{ch}(\mathcal{O}_{X_\lambda})$ (in the basis of Schubert cycles)? I am specifically interested in the first higher term, i.e. $\alpha_{|\lambda|+1}$ in the expression

$\mathrm{ch}(\mathcal{O}_{X_\lambda}) = [X_\lambda] + \sum_{c \geq |\lambda|+1} \alpha_c,$

with homogeneous terms $\alpha_c \in A^c(Gr)$. This will be some linear combination of classes $[X_{\mu}]$ where $\mu$ is an extension of the partition $\lambda$ by 1 box.

Comment: Can you work this out from the formula of Fulton and Pragacz-Ratajski?